# C# Server Object Exception

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have this code
http://pastebin.com/hCFk0FJg
Server starts and listens normally, but then when I telnet to it server throws exception on this line

```
// Call when we start receiving data
soc.BeginReceive(
    theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 
    0, 
    theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length, 
    SocketFlags.None, 
    new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), 
    soc);
```

With error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am not a professional so I can't figure out what is missing there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your parameter objects passed to .BeginReceive is or contains a null object. Basically, one of the critical pieces of data is currently set to "Nothing".

If you create a breakpoint at that line, you can hover your mouse over the various items and get information on them; at least one of them will be null. If there's only one, you found it and it's now a matter of initializing it. If there's more than one, it gets more complicated. In either case, read the documentation thoroughly - It'll likely have some example code you can browse.

Comment: This helped. Apparently socket was null. Offtopic question. Whats the best way to store sockets and then when needed send a data to specific socket?

Comment: If you want to store items and reference them specifically, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> was made for that.